# How to install and run SML/ NJ in VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code, sml

For the veteran programmers out there, how can I install and run the SML language in my VScode? Both syntax highlighting and interpretation.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

It would seem you're looking for [SML Environment](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vrjuliao.sml-environment). From Microsoft's page:

> SML Environment is an extension for Visual Studio Code, allowing short executions like EMACS sml-mode and providing a text-highlight with some auto-complete features.
>
> This project is been developed by Vinícius Julião (@vrjuliao), but the text-highlight is an updated version of Standard ML extension by Darin Morrison (@freebroccolo)

Comment: Thanks but it keeps showing this popup when I try to run a .sml file after installing Standard ML extension: "You don't have an extension for debugging 'Standard ML'. Should we find a 'Standard ML'
extension in the Marketplace?". I tried to run it with nor without debugging but the same issue happens

Here is the screenshot:
https://ibb.co/7G7ZY2s
Can you help me?
Thanks

Comment: @Azury Did you try running by following its instructions in the README or did you use some other method?